# Bootstrap two column centered container with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HERE IS ZIP TO MY FULL SOURCE: https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiI3Y2MzNDc5Ny00NDhmLTQ5YzctYjQ2MS1iYTI5ZTQ0ZmI1ZDYiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNhdWNhdUBpbmJveC5sdiJ9

[image: 1]

I have a question about coding 2 column boxes which are written in existing template.

Basically I have a PSD which represents the template of my website, but I'm a bit stuck in getting two container boxes containing the bottom table-like list with the information (see in screenshot). Next column box is divided by 2 and I thought that I could just do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">.col-md-6 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">.col-md-6 .col-md-pull-6</div>
</div>
```

Where should I actually start?

Comment: Can you please re-read your question and clarify exactly what you're trying to do. Also, read Bootstrap's docs on the grid http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I'm trying to make psd to bootstrap, and now i'm stuck of making these 2 bottom  column boxes, creating the style of it and as well seperating the second column into two.

Comment: Tom, I added source zip file to post so you can see what I have now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the 2 column and also find the screen shot attached for the below sample..

[image]

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <!-- Default panel contents -->
                    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
                    <!-- List group -->
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-push-12">
                        <pre class="text-justify">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ
                    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzZ  </pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-push-12">
                        <pre class="text-justify"> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa                 
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa
                    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAa</pre>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <pre class="text-justify"> 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 
                         OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB OB 

        </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps. Please mark is answered / if this answer is helping you solve your current issue/ problem.

Happy Learning.

Comment: Is it possible to make `list-group-items` like rows? take a look at the table at the top, it would be nice to have columns extra or there will be different for table? As you can see I have table now, but it looks very basic, removed the borders but still not an eye candy.. any styling for the table?

Comment: take a look at the bottom left box, how would you make elements there? Would you rather `<div>` and make it as one row and just copy them?

Comment: its up to you whether you want table or list, you as a developer need to decide that. You posted a question with column issue and I tried providing a solution, now you have another requirement. Can you share what have done for this & what problem you are facing. You can post a separate question for problem you are facing and the community would be able to help you.

Comment: I don't know how to group these elements and make them work properly. I decided that i could just make classes and put each thing for each class like this (one user)

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. can you share what you have done and where you are stuck. Was you 2 column issue fixed - please marked answer..